# How to test related_name in django model?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TelegramUser(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='telegramuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Token'))
    chat_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Chat id'), null=True, blank=False)
```

And I need to test `verbose_name` and `related_name` for each fields of this model.

So I'm testing `verbose_name`

```
def test_user_label(self):
    field_label = self.telegramuser._meta.get_field('user').verbose_name
    self.assertEquals(field_label,'User')
```

But if I try testing 'related_name', i got error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'related_name'
```

But this problem is not due to the fact that the field is `OneToOne`

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api), I found only how to check the `related_model`:

```
>>> field = user._meta.get_field('user')
>>> print(field.related_model)
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
```

But I never found a way to test `related_name`.

Comment: What do you mean, "test" this? This isn't something you would write a unit test for. Your verbose_name is whatever you set it to, there is no point testing this.

Comment: If you really want to, then i think you can do `str(self.telegramuser._meta.get_field('user')._meta.related_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `User` model you can check the reverse relation:

```
self.assertEquals(User._meta.get_field('telegramuser').related_name, 'telegram_user')
```

However, as Daniel says in the comments, this test isn't useful. Django should already test that `related_name` and `verbose_name` work. At most, you might have a test that creates a user and telegram user, then uses `user.telegramuser` to make sure that you can follow the one-to-one field backwards.